# SSML in Dialogflow response

Tags: dialogflow-es, ssml

Can we use SSML in dialogflow JSON Response from webhook i.e. without using Google Assistant client library.
Basically I would like to return SSML subalias in the response from my webhook hosted on AWS Lambda. 
I tried to search if it is possible using dialogflow JSON response, but not able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Added the following in

```
"textToSpeech": '<speak><sub alias="Indian Premier League"> IPL</sub></speak>'
```